# Sturm-Liouville boundary value problem with bounded function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

$$ y'' + \lambda y = 0, \quad y'(0) = 0 \quad |y(x)| < \infty \quad \text{for all } y \text{ in } (0, \infty),$$

I have tried numerous Sturm Liouville Boundary Value problems, but never done problems involving boundary conditions where there are inequalities and infinities. Is this a regular SLBVP or does it classify as a singular SLBVP.

How should I solve this?

Comment: I believe they meant that $\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)}|y(x)|<\infty$. Anything else doesn't make sense. And, they mean "for all $x \in (0,\infty)$" and not "for all $y$ in $(0,\infty)$". Someone was very careless in what they wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $|y(x)|<\infty$ just means that the function is real (doesn't take on infinite values).

Thus, you can solve this as a normal equation, finding that the general solution is (if $\lambda>0$, other cases are left to the reader)$$y(x)=c_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$

By forcing $y'(0)=0$ one finds $c_1=0$ and the solution is $c_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$.

Comment: Are we trying to say by "the function is real" that lambda cannot be complex?

Comment: No, the function is real in the sense that its values are not $\pm\infty$, as one could extend the real numbers to the extended real line and functions could take on $\pm\infty$.